# Do Seahorse and GPG terminal program work standalone?

Tags: application-development, bug-reporting, gnupg, debugging, seahorse

I have generated a Personal PGP Key with the Seahorse GUI as instructed by Launchpad. I have to manually sign a file for the Ubuntu Code of Conduct but... GPG doesn't find the Key so I need to know if this is a bug or what. I'll be reading the MAN pages for GPG to see how to import the key to GPG for that's clearly the solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like the common issue with GnuPG 2.1 and Ubuntu 16.04. Since GnuPG 2.1, the private keyring has been merged into the public keyring -- resulting in prior versions not finding the secret key any more.

Try both `gpg --list-secret-keys` and `gpg2 --list-secret-keys`; likely one shows the key but not the other.

Otherwise, make sure to always run GnuPG (and related software like Seahorse) under your normal user account and not root. GnuPG manages individual keyrings per system user.